# Mutation Observers---subtree

Tags: webkit, chromium, mutation-observers

I am reading this http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2011JulSep/1622.html and it seems that Chrome's behavior contrasts to specification. If I understood the specs correctly, defining "subtree" for an element means that changes to the subtree of that element (including the element itself) should be reported. However, when executing this piece of code, I get nothing.

```
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(e){console.log(e);})
observer.observe(document.body, {subtree:true, attributes:true});
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
```

What am I missing? Can somebody elaborate on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The documentation is unclear, but `subtree` is ignored unless you also specify `childList:true`.

The case for `attributes` and `attributeFilter` is the same.

Hope it still helps.

Answer (score 13):

According to [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/mutationobserver-api):

> **childList**:    Set to true if additions and removals of the target node's child elements (including text nodes) are to be observed.
>
> **subtree**: Set to true if mutations to not just target, but also target's descendants are to be observed.

This also explains **subtree** depending on **childList**.

Comment: what's the difference between `target's child elements` & `target's descendants`?

Comment: Child elements are the elements below the parent object (depth 1). Descendants are children of children and thus can be of any depth relative to the parent.

Answer (score 8):

In `mutationObserver` config, at least one of `attributes`, `characterData`, or `childList` needs to be set `true`.

Now, If you just set `childList: true`, then it will observe only the direct children (depth 1) of the target element and not the complete subtree.

To observe the complete subtree both `childList` and `subtree` needs to be set `true`.

e.g.

```
{
   childList: true,
   subtree: true
}
```

I hope, it's helpful.