# What is the difference between childList and subtree in MutationObjerver JS API?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, mutation-observers

I am trying to implement a delete event DOM manipulation functionality using MutationObserver JavaScript library, and this line causes me confusion:

```
const config = {attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true};
```

I did not find any explanation about what is the difference between childList and subtree, and when is it appropriate to use either one?

Can anyone clarify? Thanks!

Comment: [Children](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) are the _immediate_ descendants. The subtree includes _all_ descendants. Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit)?

Comment: Hi there.  Suggest looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560356/mutation-observers-subtree) for an explanation.  

This question is probably a duplicate

Comment: @SebastianSimon I also ended up here since the difference is well explained at all. And after reading and comparing it multiple time, still not.